# Validate XML with namesaces via XSD c#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

i have a xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Prowadzacy xmlns:ns0="http://test.com/xi/prowizja/CODO">
   <LIFNR>test</LIFNR>
   <NAME>test</NAME>
   <SMTP_ADR>test@ds.com</SMTP_ADR>
   <CALC_RULE>M</CALC_RULE>
   <STATIONS>
      <NUMBER>test</NUMBER>
      <LOCATION>test</LOCATION>
      <KDATB>test</KDATB>
      <KDATE/>
   </STATIONS>
   <STATIONS>
      <NUMBER>test</NUMBER>
      <LOCATION>test</LOCATION>
      <KDATB>test</KDATB>
      <KDATE>test</KDATE>
   </STATIONS>
</ns0:Prowadzacy>
```

and xsd like this (I've post only header of xsd):

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://orlen.pl/xi/prowizja/CODO" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://orlen.pl/xi/prowizja/CODO">
    <xsd:complexType name="Prowadzacy">
        <xsd:sequence>
```

i need to validate XML with this xsd, I was trying to do it like this, and get error about no element "ns0:Prowadzacy", i think i need to remove this attribute (or namespace in validation)?

```
private static XNamespace xn = "http://orlen.pl/xi/prowizja/CODO";
schemaSet.Add(xn.ToString(), XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsd)));
```

can any help me?

Comment: Did you generate it with XSD.EXE ?

Comment: my task to validate it, i think problem in attribute "ns0"

Answer (score 1):

Define a method as below to validate xml.

```
    public static bool ValidateXml(string schemaFilePath, string xmlFilePath)
    {
        bool isValidXml = true;
        var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
        var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
        const string xn = "http://orlen.pl/xi/prowizja/CODO";
        schemas.Add(xn, XmlReader.Create(schemaFilePath));
        doc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
            isValidXml = false;
        });
        Console.WriteLine("doc {0}", isValidXml ? "validated" : "did not validate");

        return isValidXml;
    }
```

**UPDATE:** Please try with below xsd and xml. I have made Name as required.

XSD:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://orlen.pl/xi/prowizja/CODO" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://orlen.pl/xi/prowizja/CODO">
  <xs:element name="LIFNR" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="NAME" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="SMTP_ADR" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="CALC_RULE" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="STATIONS">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="NUMBER"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="LOCATION"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="KDATB"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="KDATE"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Prowadzacy xmlns:ns0="http://test.com/xi/prowizja/CODO">
  <LIFNR>test</LIFNR>
  <NAME>test</NAME>
  <SMTP_ADR>test@ds.com</SMTP_ADR>
  <CALC_RULE>M</CALC_RULE>
  <STATIONS>
    <NUMBER>test</NUMBER>
    <LOCATION>test</LOCATION>
    <KDATB>test</KDATB>
    <KDATE/>
  </STATIONS>
  <STATIONS>
    <NUMBER>test</NUMBER>
    <LOCATION>test</LOCATION>
    <KDATB>test</KDATB>
    <KDATE>test</KDATE>
  </STATIONS>
</ns0:Prowadzacy>
```

**Note:** Now if you change namespace in xml, it will say "not valid".

Comment: try to set "Prowadzacy" to other value inside xml, and it be validated

Comment: my method totally the same, and i get error about "ns0:Prowadzacy"...prefix "ns0" make this error. I need to exclude it from validation, in what way can u do this? And i need to use thoose xsd which i provide above...